# How to duplicate a folder exactly

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu

I am trying to copy a filesystem for a device I am programming for. After so much time trying to figure out why the filesystem I was installing wasn't working I found out that `cp` didn't get the job done. I used `du -s` to check the size of the original filesystem and the one that I copied with `cp -r`, as it turns out they differ by about 150 bytes.

Something is telling me that symbolic links or some sort of kernel objects aren't being copied correctly.

Is it possible to copy a folder/file system exactly? If so how would I go about it?

Comment: It might be valuable to find out what the actual differences are with `diff -r` or something. It's quite possible that that 150 bytes isn't really a significant difference (or in fact any difference at all - it could just be metadata), and you have other issues that are causing the problems. Also, make sure your source file system is not  in use when you copy, as updates that happen during your copy may lead to an inconsistent copy.

Comment: since I have tried absolutely everything so far maybe the filesystem thing being in use is what is making the difference. I make the copy after the FS crashes so I didn't think it would be a big deal but who knows. I will get back with some `diffs` if I find something

Comment: THAT DID IT! I used @damienfrancois 's answer along with making sure my device was off and that did it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another popular option is to use `tar c source | (cd target && tar x )`. See [this linuxdevcenter.com article.](http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/lpt/18_16.html)

Answer (score 77):

Try doing this the straightforward way :

```
cp -a src target
```

from `man cp`

```
    -a, --archive
           same as -dR --preserve=all
```

It preserve rights, symlinks...

Comment: If you are doing this in a context where it is helpful to see that the copy is proceeding steadily, you can add a -v flag as well to print a running log of its operation to standard output.

Comment: Does it preserve hidden files as well?

Answer (score 15):

Here I tried all the code in my Linux. Seems [Rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) proposed by [@seanmcl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19434946/4058484) as the right one while others failed to keep *owners* and/or *some special files* or a *denied result*. The exact code is:

```
$ sudo rsync -aczvAXHS --progress /var/www/html /var/www/backup
```

Just remember to use just the directory name and **not put a slash** (`/`) or a **wildcard** (`/*`) at the end of *source* and *target* name otherwise the hidden files right below the source are not copied.

Comment: Copied every single byte using this command. Never thought `cp -R` would be so much off. Awesome, thanks!

Comment: You need to explain the arguments: -a archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (recursive, symlinks, permissions, times, group, owner, devices & specials), -c skip based on checksum, -z compress file data during the transfer, -v verbose, -A preserve ACLs, -X preserve extended attributes, -H preserve hard links, -S handle sparse files efficiently

Answer (score 3):

The most accurate way I know of copying files is with `cpio`:

```
cd /path/to/source
find . -xdev -print0 | cpio -oa0V | (cd /path/to/target && cpio -imV)
```

Not really easy to use, but this is *very* precise, preserving timestamps, owners, permissions, special files.

Comment: I try but: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted

Comment: insert a `sudo` before all instances of `cpio` and `find`: `sudo find . -xdev -print0 | sudo cpio -oa0V | (cd /path/to/target && sudo cpio -imV)`

Comment: copio doesn't support xattrs

Answer (score 2):

[Rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) is the best way to copy a file system.  They are [myriad arguments](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) that let you control exactly what is copied.

Comment: what flags could I use to make sure everything gets preserved?

Comment: I use -azvP, which probably does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do, for example to duplicate directory A -> B:

```
$ mkdir B
$ cd A
$ cp -a ./ ../B
```